# How to protect flash app from changing system time in runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Is there any way to measure time from starting flash without using system time? System time can be changed by user when flash running

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're asking here.  What do you mean by "system time"?  Are you trying to do something with the `flash.System` object, or are you concerned that comparisons based on the `Date` class can be tampered with by the end-user?  Could you show some code that you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes, comparisons based on the Date class can be tampered with by the end-user. I'm going to create a game, where time is the key, so if user will change system time, action will finish earlier. Is there any  way to measure time without Date class?

Comment: You have no control over the user's machine, or what information they decide to send you. Server-side provided time is the ONLY solution. You can account for ping if the intervals are that sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also not sure what exactly you mean but if you want to grab a time which cannot be altered by user you could e.g. call a webservice and get "accurate" time.
Check this website here http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm.
By passing parameters for a certain region to the request you will get the appropriate time.
Other than retreiving time from a server there is no way to make sure the (system)time has not been altered by user.

There is also a function called "getTimer()" which returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since your app started. Refer to this url:
[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29)

Comment: In windows getTimer works as expected and described in documentation. In linux result of calling getTimer() depends on system time, so it can be even negative. Try it :)

Comment: In that case, create an own Timer Object as mentioned by @Gary Perry

Comment: It does not help, because Timers are not accurate. You cannot guarantee that, callback of timer will be called within equal intervals of time.

Answer (score 0):

The Timer class is the interface to timers, which let you run code on a specified time sequence. Use the `timer.start()` method to start a timer. 
Add an event listener for the timer event to set up code to be run on the timer interval.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794136/how-to-protect-flash-from-change-system-time-in-runtime#comment36625944_23799659